# How do `createImageData()` and `new ImageData()` differ?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I noticed that two JavaScript API members look very similar:

- Function [CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData(width, height)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData)
- Constructor [new ImageData(width, height)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData)

How should I correctly choose which one to use? Or are they essentially interchangeable?

At a glance, one difference is that the `ImageData` constructor is marked as "This is an experimental technology / Because this technology's specification has not stabilized...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both APIs can accomplish what you want, you can use either one. If an API has a relevant feature or restriction, then you need to decide according to these facts.

Features of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData()`:

- An old stable API function, supported in all browsers and versions.
- Needs an existing 2D context object in order to create an `ImageData` object.
- Can use the form `createImageData(imagedata)` to clone an `ImageData` object.

Features of `new ImageData()`:

- An API function that is considered experimental. Not supported in any version of Microsoft Internet Explorer!
- Is preferred when creating an `ImageData` in a worker thread. (Is `ctx.createImageData()` considered thread-unsafe?)
- Is a freestanding constructor, not requiring a 2D context object first.
- Can use the form `new ImageData(array, width, height)` to build an `ImageData` based on a pixel array.

Comment: So, basically, the answer is "none".

Comment: @LeonardoRaele Disagree, how did you come to that conclusion?